# Is it possible to insert row into the child table of FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: sql, join, jdbc, foreign-keys, derby

I have three tables in my database:

```
COMPANY(ID, NAME)  
COUPON(ID, TITLE)  
COMPANY_COUPON(COMPANY_ID, COUPON_ID)
```

Company can create coupons, so when it creates coupon, coupon's ID and ID of the company will be added into `COMPANY_COUPON` table. When company deletes coupon it also will be deleted from `COUPON` and `COMPANY_COUPON` due to `FOREIGN KEY`. When I delete company it also deleted from `COMPANY` and `COMPANY_COUPON` due to `FOREIGN KEY`, but all its coupons stay in `COUPON` table, I tried to add into `COUPON` table `FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES COMPANY_COUPON(COUPON_ID)`, but because of it I can't insert new coupons into `COUPON` table.

Will be happy for answers how to create right tables and how to add something that will help to existing tables.
Maybe some joins can help with it, I'm really not strong in sql command yet, sorry...

Also, i was using this method to join `COMPANY_ID` and `COUPON_ID` in `COMPANY_COUPON` table, maybe there is some better way to do it.

```
@Override
public void linkCompanyCoupon(long companyID, long couponID) throws CouponSystemException {

    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();

    String CREATE_COUPON = "INSERT INTO COMPANY_COUPON (COMPANY_ID, COUPON_ID) VALUES (?,?)";

    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_COUPON)) {
        pstmt.setLong(1, companyID);
        pstmt.setLong(2, couponID);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new CouponSystemException("Linking company to the coupon is failed. ", e);
    } finally {
        pool.returnConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

This one is creates coupon, and inside it i use `linkCompanyCoupon();`

```
public void createCoupon(Coupon coupon) throws CouponSystemException {

    // Checking if name of the new coupon is not duplicate
    Optional<Coupon> isCouponTitleDuplicate = Optional.ofNullable(couponDBDAO.getCouponByTitle(coupon.getTitle()));

    if (!isCouponTitleDuplicate.isPresent()) {

        couponDBDAO.createCoupon(coupon);

        companyDBDAO.linkCompanyCoupon(loggedCompany, couponDBDAO.getCouponByTitle(coupon.getTitle()).getId());

    } else {
        throw new CouponSystemException("Coupon title: " + coupon.getTitle()
                + " already exists in database, titles and IDs of the coupons must be unique.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point with table `COMPANY_COUPON` ? If each coupon belongs to a single company, just store a reference to `COMPANY.ID` in table `COUPON`.

Comment: Yes, each coupon belongs to a single company, can you explain me how to do it? Or you mean just to add new field to COUPON table that contains COMPANY_ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database design is not properly normalized for your use case. Hou have a 1-to-N relationship where each company can have multiple coupons and each coupon belongs to a single company. You don't need table `COMPANY_COUPON` to represent that relationshiip. The correct way to proceed is to store a reference to `COMPANY.ID` in table `COUPON`.

```
ALTER TABLE coupon 
    ADD company_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE coupon
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_company_id FOREIGN KEY (company_id) 
    REFERENCES company(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Actually, it *is* normalized, it's just normalized *incorrectly* for the business model.

Comment: @GMB Worked well, thank you very much! Can you explain me what are they: DEFAULT 0, CONSTRAINT and fk_? And how can I add this on create table(second alert)?

Comment: @VladimirKraykin there are plenty of documentation available that describe mysql foreign keys : try [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) or [the official mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: @GMB I wouldn’t ask  if hadn’t checked first, but sometimes it’s easier to understand simply worlds of somebody than academic language of literature. But I don’t insist, I really appreciate you answering me, because that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

What you've set up is a many-to-many relationship: a company can have many coupons but a coupon can also belong to many companies. That's why the cascading delete removes the entries in the join table (COMPANY_COUPON) when you delete a COMPANY, but it does not delete any rows in COUPON because those rows may also be related to some other company. If a coupon can only belong to one company then you want a one-to-many relationship: put a `company_id` foreign key column in COUPON and get rid of the join table.